# Dot in route parameter doesn't match route in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

One of my route parameters has a dot in the route parameter. The route is `/len/:abc`. Here `abc` is going to be `-2.2,3.2,5.4`. When I call the requeust `/test/len/-2.2,3.2,5.4` I get a `404` error. When I remove the dots and call the request `/test/len/-22,32,54` this works. Can anyone please help.
Below is my routes.js code -

```
'get /test/len/:abc': {
   controller: 'TestController',
   action: 'len',
}
```

Sails version 1.5.1

Node version 14.21.2

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `skipAssets: false` option.

```js
'get /test/len/:abc': {
   controller: 'TestController',
   action: 'len',
   skipAssets: false // include dots in the variable
}
```

See: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?route-target-options